# My event onClick in my map does not work. Very strange behavior

Tags: reactjs

My Onclick on bestmovies map does not work. If I place it on a H1, for example, works. `onClick={handleClickMovie}`

```js
// imports....

const Movies = () => {
  const [popularMovies, setPopularMovies] = useState([])
  const [bestMovies, setBestMovies] = useState([])
  const [showPopUp, setShowPopUp] = useState(false)

  const handleClickMovie = () => {
    setShowPopUp(console.log('Clicked'))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getMovies() {
      const responsePopularMovies = await getPopularMovies()
      setPopularMovies(responsePopularMovies.results)

      const responseBestMovies = await getBestMovies()
      setBestMovies(responseBestMovies.results)
    }
    getMovies()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <Wrapper>
        {showPopUp ? <MoviePopUp /> : null}
        <h1>Filmes Populares</h1>
        <Content>
          {popularMovies.map(item => (
            <MovieItem movie={item} />
          ))}
        </Content>
        <h1>Filmes Bem Avaliados</h1>
        <Content>
          {bestMovies.map(item => (
            <MovieItem movie={item} onClick={handleClickMovie} />
          ))}
        </Content>
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Movies
```

MovieItem.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Cover, Score, Title } from './MovieItem.styles'

const MovieItems = ({ movie }) => {
  return (
    <Cover key={movie.id}>
      <img
        src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${movie.poster_path}`}
        alt="capas"
      />
      <Score>{movie.vote_average}</Score>
      <Title>{movie.title}</Title>
    </Cover>
  )
}

export default MovieItems
```

Comment: What's the content of `<MovieItem>`?

Comment: What is the <Wrapper> from where you took it?

Comment: If `<MovieItem>` is a custom component that you made, you need to let it be able to receive the `onClick` prop, otherwise anything that you pass to it in the JSX will be ignored.

Comment: I Will edit and place the content of  `<MovieItem>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try wrapping in a div

```
 <Content>
      {bestMovies.map(item => (
        <div onClick={handleClickMovie}>
            <MovieItem movie={item} onClick={handleClickMovie} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @anthony_718 answered, you are calling `onClick` on a JSX component. JSX components aren't in the DOM and don't have click events (although they can render HTML elements if they contain them).

If you want, you can also pass the props all the way up to an actual html element the `<Cover>` renders.

Answer (score 1):

@anthony_718's answer is correct.

The reason it didn't work it's because `<MovieItem>` doesn't have `onClick` in his props.

However, to facilitate reusability, you can modify your component like so:

```js
const MovieItems = ({ movie, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div onClick={onClick}>
      <Cover key={movie.id}>
         // ... rest of your stuff
      </Cover>
    </div>
  )
}
export default MovieItems
```

It's essentially the same solution, but by placing `<div onClick>` within the component definition, you make it more reusable than the other option.

Answer (score 0):

check this

`bestMovies.map((item, i) => { return( <MovieItem movie={item} onClick={handleClickMovie} /> )})`